How to implement paging with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration?
We use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, and Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management as client to interact with our Azure Service Bus. Our code uses paging to save performance:
managementClient = new ManagementClient(ConnectionString);
foundQueue = await FindQueue(managementClient, queueName, 100, 0);

private async Task<QueueDescription> FindQueue(ManagementClient managementClient, string queueName, int top, int skip)
{
    var allQueues = await managementClient.GetQueuesAsync(top, skip);
    foreach (var queue in allQueues)
    {
        var foundName = queue.Path;
        // ...
    }

    if (allQueues.Count == top)
    {
        return await FindQueue(managementClient, queueName, top, skip + top);
    }

    // ...
}

Now we want to migrate to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. For Paging, we use Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration:
administrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(ConnectionString);
foundQueue = await FindQueue(administrationClient, queueName, 100, 0);

private async Task FindQueue(ServiceBusAdministrationClient administrationClient, string queueName, int top, int skip)
{
    var allQueues = administrationClient.GetQueuesAsync(); // <- how to use paging here with top and skip?

    //..
}

How to implement paging with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration?

var pageIterator = administrationClient.GetQueuesAsync().AsPages(default, pageSize);
// Skip pages until the desired page number is reached -
await foreach (var page in pageIterator) {....}

The comment by @DA is correct (and should move to an answer so that it can be accepted).   The docs for "AsyncPageable.AsPages" can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.asyncpageable-1.aspages?view=azure-dotnet
